How do I continuously track the distance of an object from the camera during object detection in a video?
I'm trying to display the distance of an object from the camera, given a focal length. How do I ensure that the distance is continuously tracked in the video without much error?
I'm currently using tensor flow(mobile net ssd) for the object detection
